# Why would some of my Lightroom3 noise reduction sliders be disabled?

Tags: software, lightroom, troubleshooting, lightroom-3

I use Lightroom 3.6 and I just imported some old RAW files into it.

I can use the basic noise reduction tools but the Details and Contrast tools are disabled.

[image]

How can I get them enabled? The same camera was used on these old RAWs that I use today, so that isn't it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just solved it.

Go to the Settings Menu, select Process, and if it is Process 2003 you convert to Process 2010.

[You can read about Process 2010 here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS2bacbdf8d487e58240e1c02a1341ed8e630-8000.html)

Comment: LOL, I forgot to do that! Oh, wait... "You can accept your own answer in 2 days." :- )